# websocket calls in jmeter returning 401

Tags: websocket, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, blazemeter

Problem statement:
Jmeter webSocket request-response sampler is returning response code 401. `with Response message:Got unexpected status 401 with statusLine:HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized` [image: Reason for unauthorization is very confusing]

Questions:

- The documentation says headers are taken by default, I have NTLM auth for wss, if i add the header in HTTP header manager will it work?
- There are references that say port has to be 443 for wss communication, in my application the IP address is given as wss://optiPerf02:8081 (A new port is open for new user). How to proceed on this

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes it will, but calculating the relevant [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header value for NTLM might be tricky, see [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) for more details. Have to tried to `use existing connection` as I see some sampler which does "negotiation" so it might be a better idea to re-use the established connection as it might derive valid authentication context from the HTTP session:

   [image]
2. The references mainly [follow default ports for HTTP and HTTPS](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-09.html#rfc.section.1.7), however the WebSocket server might be running on any port.